# SELECT Recursivo (SQL)

Tags: sql, query, cte

Boa tarde!

Pessoal estou com a seguinte dificuldade:

Imagina que eu tenha uma lista de vários Clientes, e cada cliente possui um Grupo de classificação ( o Grupo de Classificação pode ser repetido para alguns clientes); 
De repente alguns clientes possuem um vínculo com outros clientes;
Preciso criar um Mapa de Vínculos em que ao pesquisar um cliente eu consiga exibir:

- todos os clientes que pertence ao mesmo Grupo que o cliente pesquisado;
- todos os clientes do grupo em que os clientes do Grupo principal possa estar vinculado Exemplo :

```
CREATE TABLE #GRUPO_CLIENTES
    (
         CODGRUPO    INT
        ,CPF_CNPJ    VARCHAR(15)
    )

    CREATE TABLE #CLIENTES
    (
         CODCLIENTE        INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
        ,NOME            VARCHAR(50)
        ,CPF_CNPJ        VARCHAR(15)
    )

    INSERT INTO #CLIENTES
    VALUES
         ('AURORA', '37306895000105')
        ,('SADIA','37306895000222') 
        ,('PERDIGAO','37306895000333')
        ,('SEARA','37306895000444')
        ,('EMIRATES', '55172540000144')
        ,('AZUL','55172540000222')
        ,('TAM S/A','55172540000333')
        ,('GOL LINHAS AEREAS S/A','55172540000444')
        ,('FISHER PRICE','62085953000157')
        ,('RI HAPPY','62085953000222')
        ,('ESTRELA','62085953000333')
        ,('MATEL','62085953000444')
        ,('DAYCOVAL','06877315000106')
        ,('ITAU','06877315000222')
        ,('SANTANDER','06877315000333')
        ,('BRADESCO','06877315000444')
        ,('HABIBS','09429621000160')
        ,('MCDONALDS','09429621000111')
        ,('BOBS','09429621000222')
        ,('BURGER KING','09429621000333')
        ,('BMW','82779204000137')
        ,('FORD','82779204000222')
        ,('FIAT','82779204000333')
        ,('CHEVROLET','82779204000444')


INSERT INTO #GRUPO_CLIENTES VALUES
            (10, '37306895000105')
        ,(10,'37306895000222') 
        ,(10,'37306895000333')
        ,(10,'37306895000444')
        ,(10,'37306895000555')
        ,(15, '30933404000107')
        ,(15,'30933404000222')
        ,(15,'30933404000333')
        ,(15,'30933404000444')
        ,(15,'30933404000555')
        ,(20,'62085953000157')
        ,(20,'62085953000222')
        ,(20,'62085953000333')
        ,(20,'62085953000444')
        ,(20,'62085953000555')
        ,(25,'06877315000106')
        ,(25,'06877315000222')
        ,(25,'06877315000333')
        ,(25,'06877315000444')
        ,(25,'06877315000555')
        ,(30,'09429621000160')
        ,(30,'09429621000111')
        ,(30,'09429621000222')
        ,(30,'09429621000333')
        ,(35,'82779204000137')
        ,(35,'82779204000222')
        ,(35,'82779204000333')
        ,(35,'82779204000444')
        ,(35,'82779204000555')


    CREATE TABLE #MAPA_RISCO_VINCULOS
    (
         ID_VINCULO        INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
        ,CNPJ_VINCULO    VARCHAR(14)
        ,CNPJ_ASSOCIADO VARCHAR(14)
        ,ATIVO            BIT
    )

    INSERT INTO #MAPA_RISCO_VINCULOS VALUES
     ( '37306895000105', '55172540000333', 1) -- AURORA+ TAM            10 + 15
    ,( '62085953000444', '37306895000444', 1) -- MATEL + SEARA        20 + 10    
    ,( '82779204000333', '62085953000222', 1) -- FIAT + RI HAPPY        35 + 20
    ,('06877315000444', '09429621000160' , 1) -- BRADESCO + HABIBS    25 + 30
```

1. Quando eu pesquisar pelo CNPJ 06877315000222 (ITAU) tem exibir:
  - todos os clientes do grupo da ITAU(BRADESCO, ITAU, SANTANDER, CAIXA), porque o cliente Bradesco foi vinculado ao cliente HABIBS;
  - todos os clientes do grupo da HABIBS(HABIBS, MCDONALDS, BURGER KING, BOBS)
2. Já quando eu pesquisar o CNPJ 82779204000137 (BMW) tem que exibir:
  - todos os clientes do grupo da BMW (BMW, FIAT, CHEVROLET, FORD) porque o cliente Fiat foi vinculado com o cliente RI HAPPY;
  - todos os clientes do grupo RI HAPPY ( RI HAPPY, MATEL, ESTRELA , FISHER PRICE);
  - todos os clientes do grupo SEARA (AURORA, SEARA, PERDIGAO, SADIA) porque ela foi vinculado ao cliente MATEL;
  - todos os clientes do grupo TAM (EMIRATES, TAM, GOL, AZUL) porque ela foi vinculado ao cliente AURORA que está no mesmo grupo que a SEARA vinculada anteriormente;

**Estava tentando fazer o seguinte procedimento:**

1. Verifico o CODGRUPO em que o cliente pesquisado ('BMW' ,82779204000137) faz parte e armazeno em uma tabela temporária todos os Cnpjs deste grupo;
2. Armazeno todos os vínculos que estes clientes possuem;

E é aqui que eu me perco. Eu não estou encontrando uma forma de verificar se os clientes vinculados ao grupo principal possuem vínculos com outros clientes de outros grupos e exibir todos em um lugar só. Até estou tentando fazer com CTE Recursivo, mas não estou encaixando a lógica necessária.
Quem puder dar ideias eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue abaixo uma proposta de consulta.

A estratégia na escrita de uma CTE recursiva é começar de um conjunto inicial de elementos e, na etapa recursiva, fazer a junção desse conjunto inicial com o conjunto de elementos que você deseja obter recursivamente.

Ou seja, neste caso específico, o conjunto inicial é o conjunto de empresas que estão no mesmo grupo que a empresa-vínculo inicial (escolhi o CNPJ 82779204000137, para ser mais didático).

O conjunto junção é a junção do conjunto inicial com a regra do mapa de vínculos (via campo `cnpj_vinculo`), em junção com o grupo de empresas de cada associação do mapa de vínculos (via campo `cnpj_associado`), em junção com o grupo de empresas do mesmo grupo (via campo `codgrupo`).

Durante a execução desta CTE, a cada "rodada" do trecho recursivo, o conjunto inicial cresce um pouco mais, retroalimentando o trecho recursivo, até que não haja mais nenhum elemento do novo conjunto passível de mapear novos elementos para si. Ou seja, até que o número de elementos da CTE converja.

```
DECLARE @vinculoCom VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @codgrupo INT

SET @vinculoCom = '82779204000137'
SET @codgrupo = (SELECT codgrupo 
                 FROM grupo_clientes 
                 WHERE cpf_cnpj = @vinculoCom)
BEGIN
    WITH ctevinculos (cpf_cnpj)
    AS (
      -- Initialization excerpt below.
       SELECT cpf_cnpj
       FROM #grupo_clientes
       WHERE codgrupo = @codgrupo
  
    UNION ALL

      -- Recursive excerpt below.
       SELECT gc2.cpf_cnpj
       FROM #mapa_risco_vinculos mrv
       INNER JOIN ctevinculos v ON mrv.cnpj_vinculo = v.cpf_cnpj
       INNER JOIN #grupo_clientes gc1 ON mrv.cnpj_associado = gc1.cpf_cnpj
       INNER JOIN #grupo_clientes gc2 ON gc1.codgrupo = gc2.codgrupo
    )
    SELECT c.codcliente, c.nome, c.cpf_cnpj
    FROM #clientes c
    JOIN ctevinculos v ON c.cpf_cnpj = v.cpf_cnpj
END
```

Veja o fiddle [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57075536d2ee2962bd7c2988307e8b86).

Comment: Marcelo, 
Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição.
Para ser verdadeiro, no início achei que não estivesse trazendo o resultado esperado, mas percebi que no script que disponibilizei existia um erro de cadastro (tive que colocar dados fictícios para não expor informação de sigilo e ai montei errado o cenário).
Após acertar o script de cadastro sua Resposta atendeu perfeitamente minha necessidade.

Muito obrigado. Eu estava tentando aprender sobre a CTE, mas não consegui assimilar tão bem a ponto de resolver meu problema.